# Python TCP Server sending message to all clients

Tags: python, sockets, tcp

I have been trying to make a TCP python server over my LAN, but I've constantly run into issues with this project. My question is: Is it possible to send a message (over TCP) to multiple clients from 1 server? (I.e. client-1 sends a message "Hello world" and it shows the message on all other clients [clients-2, clients-3]). Heres my code for the server so far:

```
import socket, time, sys
import threading

TCP_IP = input("Host IP: ")
TCP_PORT = int(input("Host Port: "))
BUFFER_SIZE = 1024

def createNewThread(function):
    threading.Thread(target=function).start()

def Listening():
    try:
        while True:
            s.listen(1)

            conn,addr = s.accept()
            threading.Thread(target=Listening).start()
            print("User joined with IP %s" % (addr[0]))
            while 1:
                data = conn.recv(BUFFER_SIZE)
                if not data: break
                conn.send(addr[0].encode("utf-8") + b': ' + data)
            conn.close()
    except ConnectionResetError as e:
        print("Connection was closed: ", e)

try:
    s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
    s.bind((TCP_IP,TCP_PORT))
    print("-----Server started-----")
    Listening()
except socket.error as e:
    print("Socket error occured. More info: ", e)
```

And heres my code for client:

```
import socket, sys, time

TCP_IP = input("Connect to Local IP: ")
TCP_PORT = int(input("Connect to Local Port: "))
BUFFER_SIZE = 1024
running = True

while running == True:
    try:
        s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
        print("Connecting...")
        s.connect((TCP_IP,TCP_PORT))
        print("Connected!")
        while True:
            MESSAGE = input("Message: ")
            if MESSAGE == "exit":
                s.close()
                raise SystemExit
            s.send(MESSAGE.encode('ascii'))
            data = s.recv(BUFFER_SIZE)
            print(data.decode("utf-8"))

        running = False
        time.sleep(20)
    except:
        print(sys.exc_info()[0])
        time.sleep(1)
```

Thanks in advance to any answers!

**Edit:**
I want the ouput to look something like this:

```
User3's IP: Message they sent
User1's IP: Message they sent
Message: What do you want to send?
```

Comment: " Is it possible to send a message (over TCP) to multiple clients from 1 server?" - Yes. What is the issue that you are facing?

Comment: @Prabhu *sigh* How then?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your code is... very weird. First thing is that you create a new thread on `accept` but you send listener to that thread instead of the client. Thus your threads never die and you have a memory and cpu leak. It's even worse: in your code the number of threads is equal to the number of **all** clients that have **ever** been connected to the server. This is bad.

Try this on the server side:

```
def client(conn):
    while True:
        data = conn.recv(BUFFER_SIZE)
        if not data:
            break
        conn.send(data)  # simple ping

def listener():
    s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
    s.bind((TCP_IP, TCP_PORT))
    s.listen(5)
    while True:
        conn, addr = s.accept()
        threading.Thread(target=client, args=(conn,)).start()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    listener()
```

The code is shorter, simpler and there are no memory/cpu leaks.

Now as for sending data to all clients. You have to keep track of them. You can achieve this by keeping a global dict of clients:

```
CLIENTS = {}
```

Now in listener you do:

```
def listener():
    s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
    s.bind((TCP_IP,TCP_PORT))
    s.listen(5)
    while True:
        conn, addr = s.accept()
        # register client
        CLIENTS[conn.fileno()] = conn
        threading.Thread(target=client, args=(conn,)).start()
```

and in client:

```
def client(conn):
    while True:
        data = conn.recv(BUFFER_SIZE)
        if not data:
            break
        # broadcast
        for client in CLIENTS.values():
            client.send(data)

    # the connection is closed: unregister
    del CLIENTS[conn.fileno()]
```

There's one little problem with that code (well actually there are several, e.g. error handling). What happens if some clients unregisters while we loop through `CLIENTS` dictionary? Python will throw an exception. Simple solution is to lock the dictionary on inserts, deletions and iterations.

Also there's a race condition if some other socket reuses previous `fileno()`. In that case you may want to generate ids for sockets manually (preferably by wrapping `socket` object with a custom class).

Note that it is possible to use `set` instead of `dict`. However you will eventually need a dict since at some point you would want to send msg to a specific client (identified by some id).

Comment: I know that my code is weird, Im not very 'organized' when it comes to these sorts of things. Thanks for help, just trying it all out now!

Comment: What is a cpu leak?

Comment: @Sam The same as memory leak: you lose a resource. In case of cpu this means that it does a pointless work and thus you lose cycles that could be doing something meaningful.

Comment: @freakish, I guess I've never heard of it as a "cpu leak" I would call it "an inefficient algorithm",  leak has the implication that you will eventually run out. You don't "run out" of cpu cycles, you are just slower than you could be.